# Trying to reinstall macOS but can’t see a hard drive when I try to reinstall macOS

Tags: macos

When trying to reinstall a new copy of macOS Sierra by using the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while going in recovery mode, when I click on Disk Utility all I see is the “OS X Base system“ , consequently I don’t see a disk to select when I select “Install macOS High Sierra”

Comment: More information needed. Do you have a hard drive (or SSD), and if so what's on it now (e.g. blank, functional OS, broken OS, which version, etc)? Also, exactly how are you starting up into recovery mode?  What version of macOS recovery are you using (you can open Terminal, and run the command `sw_vers` to find out).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if your HD/SSD is not visible in Disk Utility it means it is dead, missing or otherwise disconnected.

Even if it is formatted in a "foreign" file system (EXT4, NTFS, etc.) Disk Utility will still see it and allow you to reformat or re-partition it.

If you feel comfortable opening up your Mac you might want to think about checking the connectors to the drive and making sure they are firmly connected.

However, you didn't include what type of Mac you have so it will be difficult, if not impossible, to give any more assistance without a lot more information, e.g. model number, what you have already done, what the drive *should* be, etc.

If you are not comfortable opening up your Mac then it is time to take it in for service.